# Which approach is best, make a multiple file or single file?

Tags: c#, executable, portable-executable

If I create Windows Application in C#.Net. and it will run on more than 15k clients machine. My Application doing the below process.

1. Read/Write data from the local database. DB will be RDBMS.
2. Read/Write Settings to Local Setting file.
3. Logging.
4. Application auto-update

I'm updating in my application in every 3 to 6 week due to business or client requirements.

For example If I use 3 layer application architecture. So I should create multi-part Executable or Merge all DLLs in the single executable? I just want to know what are the pros and cons in both methods.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can pack your entire application into a single executable. You can even write your entire code into a single method - even on a single line. If this is a good idea, depends on if and how your want to re-use the code and if other clients may use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET you can use some AutoUpdater to avoid bothering yourself with releasing multiple DLLs or a single DLL.

If your app is hosted on a server, you can host a zip file of the app there along with a version file. For example, I'm updating my app every 2 weeks and I have Azure build and zip the app every release, publishing it to GitHub Releases. At the same time, in my master branch there is a version.xml keeping trace of the latest version online. 
All this is possible with [AutoUpdater.NET](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Autoupdater.NET.Official)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Keelah. this is good lib to manage Updates. Thank you again.